# How to use user inputted value "X" to print all values smaller or larger than "X" value from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, max, java-stream, min

So basically I am trying to print all values from arraylist that are smaller or bigger than user inputted value.
For example if I input "500" it would print all values that are smaller than that and then I could do same to bigger values.
How do I go forward with it? Currently it uses stream to print values that are smaller or bigger than "30"

Currently I have tried few methods like using completely new value variable for the user inputted value. I have hard time picturing how to move forward with this.

I have also tried to use for loop to make whole system but I found that it didn't work like intended so I got recommended to use .stream instead.

Main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClass {

        public static void main( String [] args ) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
            Container list = new Container();

        System.out.println("Enter amount (1-5)");
        int count = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) { 
            System.out.println("Enter Type"); 
            String type = sc.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter Type2");
            String type2 = sc.nextLine();   

            System.out.println("Enter value");
            int value = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            MoreInfo moreInfo = new MoreInfo(type, type2);
            Info info = new Info(moreInfo, value);
            list.Add(info);     


        }

        list.PrintAll();
        System.out.println("Smaller than 30");
        list.PrintSmaller();
        System.out.println("Larger than 30");
        list.PrintLarger();



    }
}
```

Container class that does contain methods for min and max
Those methods can be found from bottom of the class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Container {
    private MoreInfo moreInfo;
    public ArrayList <Info> InfoArray;

    public Container() {
        InfoArray = new ArrayList <Info>();
        this.setMoreInfo(moreInfo);
    }


    public MoreInfo getMoreInfo() {
        return moreInfo;
    }


    public void setMoreInfo(MoreInfo moreInfo) {
        this.moreInfo = moreInfo;
    }


    public boolean Add(Info addInfo) {
        return InfoArray.add(addInfo);
    }




public void PrintAll() {

        Iterator<Info> iter = InfoArray.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Info info = iter.next();

            System.out.println( info.getValue() + info.getMoreInfo().getType2() + info.getMoreInfo().getType());

        }
    }


public void PrintSmaller() {

    InfoArray.stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() < 30()).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

public void PrintLarger() {

    InfoArray.stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > 30()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

next class "MoreInfo" contains variables

```
package test;

public class MoreInfo {

    private String type;
    private String type2;

    public MoreInfo(String Type, String Type2) {
        this.type2 = Type2;
        this.type = Type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType2() {
        return type2;
    }

    public void setType2(String Type2) {
        this.type2 = type2;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return type + " " + type + " " + type2;
    }
}
```

Final "Info" class contains variables too

```
package test;



public class Info {

        private MoreInfo moreInfo;
        private int value;

        public Info(MoreInfo moreInfo, int value) {
            this.moreInfo = moreInfo;
            this.value = value;
        }

        public MoreInfo getMoreInfo() {
            return moreInfo;
        }

        public int getValue() {
            return value;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return moreInfo + " " + value;

        }

}
```

Figured that it would be easier for everyone to understand if I would post full code rather than snippets of it.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Your code looks fine, except for some coding-convention issues. What is it that you want exactly??

Comment: you just commented a few lines of code. How does it say what you want??

Comment: @raviiii1 PrintSmaller and PrintLarger parts needs to have user inputted value instead of me it having "locked value" like 30. Currently it compares values of arraylist to "30" and selects picks up smaller or bigger values. What I want to do is to change that "30" to something user can choose so for example user could type 56 and it would print values that are smaller or bigger than that.

Comment: Do you know how to use parameterized functions? Use this link for help http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~reid/web/javaparams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the number you want to find smaller numbers of into a variable, say

```
int arg;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)
arg = sc.nextInt()
```

Modify your print smaller and print larger functions to have 1 parameter, like so...

```
public void PrintSmaller(int number) {

    InfoArray.stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() < number()).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

public void PrintLarger(int number) {

    InfoArray.stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() > number()).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Pass the arg into the method calls...

```
System.out.println("Smaller than " + arg);
list.PrintSmaller(arg);
System.out.println("Larger than " + arg);
list.PrintLarger(arg);
```